# res.body is always empty in node.js express post routine

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Hello I'm desperate because of the problem that req.body is always empty in the express, body-parser post routine.

I'm using node v16.19.0.

My code looks like this:

```
"use strict";

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    const value = req.body;
    console.log("post:");
    console.log(value);

    // resend json data
    res.send(value);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("listen at port 3000");
});
```

The package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

For the POST I use on Windows:

```
curl.exe -X POST -H 'content-type: application/json;' -d '{"message":"11111"}'  http://localhost:3000/post
```

The internet is full of examples and descriptions of the same or similar problems, but none of them worked for me. I've tried a lot now, but the error persists.
Does anyone have an idea where the problem could lie?

Comment: body-parser uses the debug lib, set into env `DEBUG=body-parser:json` or `process.env.DEBUG='body-parser:json'` you should see the errors as to why it cant parse it

Comment: Hello Lawrence Cherone thanks for the hint, when I set the environment variable, there are actually some outputs:
  body-parser:json content-type "application/json;" +0ms
  body-parser:json skip parsing +1ms
This really seems to be related to the semicolon... if I omit it, other exceptions come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes on Windows, not single quotes:

```
curl.exe -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{\"message\":\"11111\"}"  http://localhost:3000/post
```

Comment: ...and it has to be run from cmd in PowerShell it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

The content type isn't supposed to have a trailing semicolon:

```
-H 'content-type: application/json'
```

Comment: Hi robertklep if I omit the semicolon I get an exception SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 1 in ...\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19

Comment: Yes, you were right, there were two errors: the semicolon and the double quotes.